# Does a scout get skirmish extra damage on a ready action or AOO?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm asking because I'm confused after reading the errata of the skirmish ability in the complete adventurer.

Original:

> She deals an extra
>   1d6 points of damage on **all** attacks she makes during
>   any round in which she moves at least 10 feet. The extra
>   damage applies **only to attacks taken during the scout’s
>   turn**.

Errata:

> She
>   deals an extra 1d6 points of damage on **all** attacks she
>   makes during any round in which she moves at least 10
>   feet away from where she was at the start of her turn. The extra damage applies only to attacks made after the
>   scout has moved at least 10 feet.

What I want to know is, does a scout get skirmish extra damage on a ready action or during an attack of opportunity?
Is the answer different in the original version from the answer in the errata version?

My current thinking is:

Original Ready (not sure) / AoO No

Errata Ready Yes / AoO Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the original wording, no - a readied action does not take place "on your turn" and as a result would not get the bonus damage.

With the errata, which I personally suggest you use, yes - the scout gets the bonus damage once she's moved ten feet, and continues to enjoy the bonus damage (and armor class, when that comes online) until the beginning of her next turn (which is how "one round" effects end in 3.X).

I wouldn't necessarily suggest trying to use readied actions for this, since they can be inefficient for melee, but a scout with a reach weapon and some combat reflexes may serve you well.